# Failing to insert new item in database(db.saveCHanges fails)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, insert, savechanges

at the line  `db.SaveChanges();` of the execution. I get the following error.

Note: I am performing an insert.

[image]

ERROR :

> Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.ProductVariant' with unique index 'ProductVarioant_Barcode'.The statement has been terminated.

Comment: As the error clearly says - obviously, you have a **unique** constraint (or index) on `ProductVariant.Barcode` and you're trying to insert a second row with a duplicate value. Just don't do this .

Comment: You must make sure when you insert that in your table the data increments instead of sending yourself ids which can be duplicate and will fail on insertion

Comment: edit your question and Shoe your code (write it down here). Code for the insert (hidden below your dialogue in picture) and better to also show your Product_variant class (would be in models)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error indicates that you are trying to insert a duplicate value inside Barcode column of ProductVariant table. While there is an unique constraint on ProductVariant.Barcode.